# How to query SQLITE database from inside an HTML script

Tags: php, sqlite

What's the write syntax to query an SQLITE database from inside an HTML script?
The code below (which btw works perfectly when used in a separate php file) doesn't return anything in the textarea....

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
<p>Patient search:</p> 
<textarea id="SearchBoxPt" textarea name="SearchBoxPt" style="height: 30px; resize: none; width: 600px;">       
</textarea></p> 

<button type="button" onclick="populateField_SearchPt()">Load Pt 1</button>

<script>
function populateField_SearchPt() 
{        
    <?php
    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open('Anagrafica.db');
        }
    }

    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db)
    {
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else 
    {
        echo "Opened database successfully\n\n";
    }

    $results = $db->query('SELECT name FROM Anagrafica WHERE hospital_ID="1"');
    ?>    

    document.getElementById ("SearchBoxPt").value = $results; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to fetch your result: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php

Comment: And you'll also need to echo out your hospital name.

Comment: And your html file must be parsed as Php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

**PHP**

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('Anagrafica.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db)
{
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
}

$hId = $_GET['hId']; //we're getting the passed hId as a paramater in the url

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM Anagrafica WHERE hospital_ID=:id");
$query->bindValue(':id', $hId, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchArray();
echo $results['name'];
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Enter Hospital Id:
    <input id="HospitalId" type="number" value="1">
</p>

<p>Patient search:</p> 
<textarea id="SearchBoxPt" textarea name="SearchBoxPt" style="height: 30px; resize: none; width: 600px;">       
</textarea>
</p> 

<button type="button" onclick="populateField_SearchPt()">Load Pt 1</button>

<script>
function populateField_SearchPt() 
{
    var inputId = document.getElementById("HospitalId").value; //we get the user input value and put it in a var

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "path/to/yourPhpFile.php?hId=" + inputId, true); // we're passing the hId to the server as a parameter
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("SearchBoxPt").value = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.send(); 

}
</script>
```

Comment: try to go to localhost/path/to/yourPhpFile.php?hId=1 and check the output result

Comment: Blank page... I have noticed some differences in the quotes between your initial php code and the latest one with hld. Could that be the reason? 

$hId = $_GET['hId']; //we're getting the passed hId as a paramater in the url

$results = $db->query("SELECT name FROM Anagrafica WHERE hospital_ID=$hId")->fetchArray();

//Get specific entry - hard coded
$results = $db->query('SELECT name FROM Anagrafica WHERE hospital_ID="1"')->fetchArray();

Comment: try escaping the hId like this: $results = $db->query("SELECT name FROM Anagrafica WHERE hospital_ID=" . $db->escapeString($hId))->fetchArray();

Comment: Nothing... I still get an empty page

Comment: The problem is in WHERE hospital_ID=$hId, but I don't know the correct syntax to combine them

Comment: did you use the last statement above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145492/discussion-between-sic-sic-and-jeddi).

Answer (score 1):

You can not put **php** scripts in **javascript** knowing that **php** is executed in the server side and not on the browser.

The solution is to keep your **php** code into a seperated file and make an **ajax** call to your php on every button click to retreive data from database.

**PHP**

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('Anagrafica.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db)
{
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
}

$results = $db->query('SELECT name FROM Anagrafica WHERE hospital_ID="1"')->fetchArray();
echo $results['name'];
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Patient search:</p> 
<textarea id="SearchBoxPt" textarea name="SearchBoxPt" style="height: 30px; resize: none; width: 600px;">       
</textarea>
</p> 

<button type="button" onclick="populateField_SearchPt()">Load Pt 1</button>

<script>
function populateField_SearchPt() 
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "path/to/yourPhpFile.php", true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("SearchBoxPt").value = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.send(); 

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but the PHP must have some issues because it doesn't retrieve the value...

Comment: Are you sure about echo $results['name']; ?

Comment: I have updated the php file (line 16). Try it and feedback me

Comment: Also ensure you are using a correct path to your php file... if your php file is in the same folder as your html file then call open() method like this: xhttp.open("GET", "yourPhpFileName.php", true);

Comment: Awesome! :-) Great answer. Thank you so much

Comment: What if I wanted to extract another record, for example another hospital_ID number? How can I pass this variable from the HTML page to PHP?

Comment: Who should provide the hospital_ID number? you or a user?

Comment: The user by entering a value in a textfield for example